How do you find the active element of an object's edit mode components (verts, points, faces, loops, ..whatever) using python?
Where does blender store the information for the active element for an object?
For example, I can tab in and out of edit mode for a mesh, and the active element remains the same. This is the same for various non-mesh object types as well. The program is keeping track of which element is active somewhere, and I'm looking to figure out where that is and how to access it (specifically from a python script). I am aware that, specifically for a mesh object, you can convert the thing to a bmesh and use the selection history to get the last selected item (i.e. the active one), but this is specific to only mesh objects and does not really have anything to do internally with the active element. (It is just a workaround that gets the desired result cause the last selected element just so happens, also, to be the active one.)

bpy.context.active_object

The title and body of your question seem like they ask two different things ? Do you want to track the active object or do you want to track the selected components of the active object ?
